# Error in Webservice Axis

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, tomcat, axis

I have a problem with my webservice. I use Tomcat and Axis. I use MySQL to connect to my DB and when I use a service to request a SELECT appears this error:

```
Jul 26, 2013 10:45:28 PM org.apache.axis.InternalException <init>
SEVERE: Exception:
java.lang.Exception: Couldn't find a matching Java operation for WSDD operation "rating" (6 args)
at org.apache.axis.InternalException.<init>(InternalException.java:71)
at org.apache.axis.description.JavaServiceDesc.loadServiceDescByIntrospection(JavaServiceDesc.java:902)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.initServiceDesc(JavaProvider.java:477)
  at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.getInitializedServiceDesc(SOAPService.java:286)
  at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.makeNewInstance(WSDDService.java:500)
  at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
  at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
  at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getService(WSDDDeployment.java:427)
  at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getService(FileProvider.java:231)
  at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getService(AxisEngine.java:311)
  at org.apache.axis.MessageContext.setTargetService(MessageContext.java:756)
  at org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper.invoke(URLMapper.java:50)
  at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
  at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
  at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
  at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:239)
  at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
  at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: and your code ? where operation rating is defined?

Comment: Not without seeing the code that generated the error, they can't tell you what the error is, or how to fix it. They could make some guesses. My guess is that the jar file where "rating" is defined isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because upper in init method name?

try this:

```
public void rating(int idUser, int idRestaurante,String Nome, int Rating, java.sql.Date Data, java.sql.Date Hora ) throws Exception {
...
}
```